# Spring Batch failed to get job context value during restart where value was set before failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using spring batch 3 with db2 server.The issue is on restarting failed job using spring job opertor, the value of newFileStatus  from job context is null. The value was used to decide next step.

```
if (BatchStatus.STARTED.equals(executions.getStatus())) {
    executions.setEndTime(new Date());
    executions.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
    executions.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
    jobRepository.update(executions);
    logger.info("Restart Status : Restarted for Start Status ");
    jobOperator.restart(executions.getId());
} else if (BatchStatus.FAILED.equals(executions.getStatus())) {
    loadCache();
    logger.info("Restart Status : Restarted for Failed Status ");
    jobOperator.restart(executions.getId());
} else {// For COMPLETED AND UNKNOWN Status
    //New Run
}
```

and in tasket to get value from context after restart

```
@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    logger.info("Step Execution Status : " +       this.stepExecution.getStatus());
    ExitStatus exitStatus;

    if (this.stepExecution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.FAILED)) {
        exitStatus = ExitStatus.FAILED;

    } else if (this.stepExecution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED)) {
        ExecutionContext jobContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        boolean newFilesStatus = (Boolean) jobContext.get("newFilesArrived");
        //based on newFileStaus next step will be determined
        if(newFilesStatus){
            //return newStep
        }else{
            //skipe new step
        }

    return exitStatus;
}
```

DB Driver - StarSql drive

Thanks

Comment: _"the value from job context is null"_ -- this is very unclear. What value from what job context.  You must do a better job of explaining what values are incorrect and what you expect them to be.

Comment: @Jim Garrison modified question